# Docker: Write in shared volumes with different UID being sudo

Tags: docker

I have a docker with a bind-mounted volume.
The permissions for the bind-mounted volume are for the user "jep" with UID 1005, while the user in the image has the name "user" and 1000 as UID and is in the sudoers group. So when running a container like:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd):/home/user/ws:rw" image
```

I get permissions error when trying to do anything:

```
user@f029839700b8 ~/ws: mkdir tmp
mkdir: cannot create directory 'tmp': Permission denied
```

I tried running a new container like:

```
docker run -it --rm -u 1005 -v "$(pwd):/home/user/ws:rw" image
```

So I don't have permission issues anymore, however, the user inside the container has no name, and due to this I cannot run any sudo commands:

```
I have no name!@297c1088b254:/home/user/ws$sudo
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
```

How can I overcome this issue without changing the owner of the binded-volume in the host machine? I cannot either modify the image.

Comment: You should never need `sudo` inside a container at all; consider that anything you do in a `docker exec` debugging shell will be lost as soon as the container exits.  What are you actually trying to do here?  (Can you do it in the Dockerfile instead, or outside of the container environment entirely?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `dockerfile`, using `FROM <unchangeable image>`, change user and build your own image.
2. If the app doesn't need sudo and you just need it for the console, you might give the sudo user explicitly: `docker exec -u 1000 ..`
3. For using local user in docker container you may mount the local users/group inside the container. Then they are known. Due to read-only flag it is quite ok in aspect of security..

```
docker run -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro
# Either (for current user)
-u $(id -u):$(id -g) --group-add sudo
#or manually
-u 1005:<gid> --group-add sudo
```

If all no: There is no possibility to mount with different user. People crying since ages for a feature like that. Like [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7198) or [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259).

Comment: Sure I could customize my dockerfile, however I don't like this option as it would be necessary to customize the dockerfile depending on the user running the container, as they will haver different UIDs.
I need to run sudo as I need to install some custom made libraries and check everything is working properly.
Adding a new user named "user" in the host machine to match the one in the image and giving it permission is a feasible option, but still don't like that new files and folders created inside the volume will have "user" as owner.

Comment: Then it would be feasible to run as `docker run -u 1005` and use `docker exec -u 1000` to install and do the checks? It is not necessary to maintain an own `dockerfile` for each user. Will edit..

Comment: The solution number 3 looks promising to me. I also mounted /etc/shadow so the password is shared. Howver when doing sudo, I'm told I'm not in the sudoers list, even that when checking "$ groups username" I see the sudoers group. Any idea?

Comment: What's the base image? Sudoers List is in /etc/sudoers

Comment: Unfortunately I have no U22 running and no time to prove. Don't know where your sudoer is located on base OS. Did you check `/etc/sudoers.d` also? It might be the case your user is there. So edit sudoers (but in case of updates manual edits of sudoers is deleted) or mount sudoers.d to container.

Comment: Apparently when using -u $(id -u):$(id -g), inside the container the user only pertains to its own group, but no sudoers. Adding the flag --group-add sudo solves the problem

Comment: Nice find. Is my edit correct?